# Global Mixins to Nuxt v2.4 : undefined

Tags: nuxt.js

After upgraded my Nuxt project from 1.4 to 2.4.0, my global mixins does not work anymore.

I tried to set it only in SSR mode, only for Client or only for Server, nothing worked.

In my plugins/mixins file, I import all mixins required and check is they exists with a console.log... and it does... But when I open the application, nothing is recognized.

**plugins/mixins.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";

import UtilMixins from "../mixins/Util";
import MomentMixins from "../mixins/Moment";
import GlobalMixins from "../mixins/Global";

Vue.mixin(UtilMixins);
Vue.mixin(MomentMixins);
Vue.mixin(GlobalMixins);
```

**nuxt.config.js**

```
  plugins: [
    "~/plugins/mixins.js"
  ],
```

**component using one mixin (exemple, a filter)**

```
{{ 'test' | uppercase }}
```

**uppercase mixin**

```
export default {
  filters: {
    uppercase(value) {
      return value.toUpperCase() || "";
    }
  }
}
```

**Console's errors**

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve filter: uppercase
(found in <Src/client/pages/login.vue> at src/client/pages/login.vue)
```

Any idea ? thanks a lot :)

Comment: The code seems fine. The only issue I can see is the missing closing bracket for the filters object of the uppercase mixin.

Comment: Thank for reading and for your reply !
I just copied a small part of the code... And I did not write it well... sorry about that...
Unfortunately, methods, filters, computed, data.. everything is not working...
I had to import all needed mixins in every component... :/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the NuxtJS documentations, if the plugin is located in `node_modules` and exports an ES6 module, you may need to add it to the `transpile` build option:

```
module.exports = {
  build: {
    transpile: ['mixins']
  }
}
```

This worked for me. Although I haven't tried it for multiple global mixins but you can refer [here](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/plugins/) for more details on adding global mixins in NuxtJS.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is add the below code to your layout file.
notice that direction of your global.js must be change .

```
<script>
    import vue from "vue";
    import global from "~/mixins.js/global.js";
    vue.mixin(global);

    export default {
      mixins: [global]
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score -4):

try moving your mixins folder to /assets and then in your plugins/mixins.js:

```
import Vue from "vue";

import UtilMixins from "~assets/mixins/Util";
import MomentMixins from "~assets/mixins/Moment";
import GlobalMixins from "~assets/mixins/Global";

Vue.mixin(UtilMixins);
Vue.mixin(MomentMixins);
Vue.mixin(GlobalMixins);
```